# boost::serialization with member function and free function

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I have a class mat4 from 3rdparty open source math library. It doesn't have own serialization method, so I've created a separate header in my main project that contains a serialization of matrix mat4:

```
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, mat4 & matrix, const unsigned int version)
{
// some serialization of matrix goes here...
}

} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

It worked perfectly until later when I added serialization directly to class mat4 and forgot to remove old serialization:

```
struct mat4 
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive> 
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {           
         ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(data);    
    } 
    // some other members and functions goes here
};
```

After such modification the free function serialize was called.
Could you please explain why the free function was called instead of mat4 member function? Probably, there is some simple rule in standard that I missed.

When I comment out the free function - member function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is due to the technique used by `boost::serialization` to allow both a free function & member functions. Basically there's a free function with the following signature:

```
 template< typename Archive, typename Type >
 void serialize( Archive& a_Arch, Type& a_Inst, const unsigned int a_Version )
 {
       a_Inst.serialize( a_Arch, a_Version );
 }
```

When C++ considers a match for a function the one that is most specialized wins out, which means that any free function where `Type` is less generic, such as the user defined free serialization functions always win. If there is none, the above function wins out which is only well formed for `Type` with a serialize member that accepts an archive & version.